# Sendmail is unable to send letters to the internet (only local mail is being sent)

Tags: centos, sendmail

I'm using centos 5 and sendmail on intranet server. Local mail is being delivered perfectly, but when i try to deliver email to gmail, for example (or any other service outside intranet) i find following errors in my logs:

```
Jan 16 16:50:32 testlink sendmail[27713]: r0GCoVi5027711: to=<example@gmail.com>,
ctladdr=<webdev@testlink.ru.corp.domain.com> (502/502), delay=00:00:01,
xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120332, relay=alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
[173.194.68.27], dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: 
Connection refused by alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

one more important thing - server is not accessible from internet, but i can access internet from my server..

Please advice where should i search the problem.. i understand that i should setup sendmail somehow (currently i'm using default configuration that was set by yum), but what settings (or at least direction)... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Quite likely your own firewall or service provider that blocks port 25 outgoing connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run `ifconfig` in command line. perhaps something is wrong with your IP

also look into `iptables -L`

`netstat -nap` should have a string

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      5275/sendmail
```

check if provider blocks port 25:

```
telnet smtp.ukr.net 25
```

Comment: server has normal local intranet 10.250.*.* ip, webserver is accessbile from other local machines.

Comment: when you trying to connect to another server in internet, you need to tell your external IP-adress. otherwise external server can't send you any info as answer.

Comment: also ctladdr should be a valid email

Comment: found a solution with forwarding emails through corporate official mail server. Thanks very much for help!